# Calling handler.removeCallbacks(run) from latAndLong method throws a nullpointerexception

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I am trying to get longitude and latitude of the user after some seconds. The runnable should repeat the method for some seconds. if the longitude and latitude is gotten the runnable should stop.

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<String> carModelAL;
Spinner spinner;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
String CAR_MODEL_URL = "http://192.168.0.195:85/tranxavApi/public/api/get-car-model";
String modelValue;
Button btn;
Intent intent;
TextView detail, selectModel;
final static Handler handler = null;
Runnable runnable;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

    final Handler  handler = new Handler();

    detail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/RobotoCondensedBold.ttf");
    detail.setTypeface(type);

    selectModel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectModel);
    Typeface typeModel = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/RobotoCondensedBold.ttf");
    detail.setTypeface(typeModel);

    carModelAL = new  ArrayList<String>();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.carModelSP);
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(LocationActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, carModelAL));
    getCarModel(CAR_MODEL_URL);

    sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String likelyProblem = sharedPreferences.getString("likelyProblem","");
    Log.i("info", likelyProblem);


    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.detailBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pd = new ProgressDialog(LocationActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("\tPlease Wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

            sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (sharedPreferences.contains("email") && sharedPreferences.contains("likelyProblem")) {

                 runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String modelSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email","");
                        String likelyProblem = sharedPreferences.getString("likelyProblem","");
                        Log.i("info", likelyProblem);
                        latAndLong(modelSelected, email, likelyProblem);
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                    }
                };

                handler.post(runnable);

            }
        }
    });
}

private void latAndLong(final String modelSelected, final String email, final String likelyProblem){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    GeoLocation geoLocation = new GeoLocation(getApplicationContext());
    Location l = geoLocation.getLocation();

    if (l != null){

        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        pd.dismiss();
        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        double lng = l.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + lat + "\n Lon: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationSender locationSender = new LocationSender(lat, lng, email, modelSelected, likelyProblem);
        sendNetworkRequest(locationSender);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LocationActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Message has been sent to the mechanic he will be there in 5 mins. After he finishes click procced to continue.");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Proceed >>>",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                                    dialog.dismiss();
                        intent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, ProblemsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }else{

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Log

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.system2.tranxav, PID: 29069
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.system2.tranxav.LocationActivity.latAndLong(LocationActivity.java:150)
                  at com.example.system2.tranxav.LocationActivity.access$000(LocationActivity.java:56)
                  at com.example.system2.tranxav.LocationActivity$1$1.run(LocationActivity.java:131)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

I have tried making the handler static as described by this site

[Calling handler.removeCallbacks from onDeleted method in a widget throws a nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710181/calling-handler-removecallbacks-from-ondeleted-method-in-a-widget-throws-a-nullp)

but it did not work. Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I declared handler in oncreate method instead of inside the class